# Cookie php deleted when browser close

Tags: php, cookies

I have a problem with my cookie now, that when I set the `expire` day in 90 days after closing and open the browser again the cookie is deleted also. what is the problem here? cause i set the cookie `expire` correctly.

here is my code setting the cookie:

```
<?php
   $expire = time() + (86400 * 90);
   setcookie('active', true, $expire, '/', '', false, true);
?>
```

Comment: have you tried with another browser ?

Comment: yes in all browser still the same. @Bdloul

Comment: The value of the cookie is supposed to be a string, can you try "true" instead of true ? 
Also try one hour first, your browser might refuse long lasting cookies. And lastly try with setting the last argument to false rather than true ($httpOnly), as depending how you check that your cookie it could be the issue (With $httpOnly cookies are supposed to only be accessible on the server, so if you are using chrome console or something like that you won't see it).